# asp.net mvc 3 remote attribute passing 3 fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I want to pass three field to my controller using RemoteAttribute. How can i do it?

```
 public int ID1 { get; set; }  
 public int ID2 { get; set; }  

 [Remote("CheckTopicExists", "Groups", AdditionalFields = "ID1", ErrorMessage = " ")]  
 public string Topic { get; set; }   

        public ActionResult CheckTopicExists(string topic, int ID1,int ID2)   
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

How can i pass three field to that function?

Answer (score 35):

You could separate them by comma:

```
AdditionalFields = "ID1, ID2"
```

Full example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ID1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }

    [Remote("CheckTopicExists", "Home", AdditionalFields = "ID1, ID2", ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public string Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel
        {
            ID1 = 1,
            ID2 = 2,
            Topic = "sample topic"
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult CheckTopicExists(MyViewModel model)
    { 
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ID1)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ID2)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Topic)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Topic)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Topic)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: @Avinash, great, so maybe you could mark this post as answer if it was helpful to you?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Avinash is dead. Anyway thanks very much. It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of sending dates, sometimes controller receive date in a wrong format: was dd/mm/yyyy, receive mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
public ActionResult CheckTopicExists(MyViewModel model)
```

If you use

```
public ActionResult CheckTopicExists(FormCollection Collection)
```

then you can reuse the code for other classes as well